# spring security bad credentials distinguish between invalid username or password

Tags: java, spring-security

In Spring Security, we can get the bad credentials exception if the username/password are not correct.

From DOC: [Spring Framework Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/BadCredentialsException.html)

```
java.lang.Object
  java.lang.Throwable
    java.lang.Exception
      java.lang.RuntimeException
        org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException
         org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException
```

Is there any exception class or way to distinguish between username invalid OR password invalid?

Something like the following:

```
catch(BadCredentialsException e) {
    if(usernameInvalid) {
        // invalid username
    } else {
        // password invalid
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
 public class SampleDaoAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {

        @Override
        protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails 
userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)
                throws AuthenticationException {
                setHideUserNotFoundExceptions(false);
                super.additionalAuthenticationChecks(userDetails, authentication);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would do the call to setHideUserNotFoundException in the constructor instead.

Comment: Which constructor? I can only see void methods here. You are saying to use constructor SampleDaoAuthenticationProvider to initialize it I think.

Comment: add one public SampleDaoAuthenticationProvider() { super(); setHideUserNotFoundException(false);}

Comment: So now if username is incorrect then I will get the UsernameNotFoundException and if password is incorrect then I will get the  BadCredentialsException? Thus distinguishing between the two and resolving my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Warning: it's not good security practice to do so.**
But if you realy don't want to hide `UsernameNotFoundException` you can configure the `AuthenticationProvider` (if it extends from `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`) to throw it instead of a `BadCredentialException` by using `setHideUserNotFoundExceptions`.

JavaDoc Extract:

> By default the `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` throws a `BadCredentialsException` if a `username` is not found or the `password` is incorrect. Setting this property to `false` will cause `UsernameNotFoundException`s to be thrown instead for the former. Note this is considered less secure than throwing `BadCredentialsException` for both exceptions.

example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider())
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider impl = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        impl.setUserDetailsService(yourUserDetailsService());
        impl.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        impl.setHideUserNotFoundExceptions(false) ;
        return impl;
    }
```

Comment: I have a class that extends DaoAuthenticationProvider and that class overrides additionalAuthenticationChecks() method of Spring. I can access setHideUserNotFoundExceptions from there. So I believe that I can use that setter method in that class itself.