# Spring security UserNotFoundException not show error message in Spring Boot with JSP view template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, spring-security

I'm creating a web application with **Spring Boot** and JSP. I have implemented the Spring Security and I am overriding the `loadUserByUsername()` method, when the user is not found, I'm throwing `UsernameNotFoundException("User not found")` with a message. Now I want to show a proper message in my login page, how can I achieve that?

**MyUserDetailsService.java**

```
    package in.bushansirgur.security.service;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Set;

    import javax.transaction.Transactional;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
    import org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityMessageSource;
    import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import in.bushansirgur.security.entity.Role;
    import in.bushansirgur.security.entity.User;

    @Service
    public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException{
            User user = userService.findUserByEmail(email);
            if(user == null || user.getActive() == null){
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found!");
            }

            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getUserAuthority(user.getRoles());
            return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
        }
        ...
    }
```

**LoginController.java**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/login", "/"})
        public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(name="error", required = false)String error, 
                @RequestParam(name="logout", required = false)String logout, HttpServletRequest request
                ) throws UnknownHostException {     
            // Port
            String portNumber = environment.getProperty("server.port");
            // Local address
            String hostAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
            String hostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
            System.out.println("Host address:"+hostAddress+" Host name:"+hostName+" Port number:"+portNumber);
            // Remote address
            InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress().getHostAddress();
            InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress().getHostName();
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("login");

            if(error!=null) {
                mv.addObject("message", "Invalid Username and Password!");
            }

            if(logout!=null) {
                mv.addObject("logout", "User has successfully logged out!");
            }
            System.out.println("context path:"+request.getContextPath());
            return mv;              
        }
```

**login.jsp**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
    <c:set var="contextRoot" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <style>
    .help-block {
        color: #ff0000;
    }
    </style>
    <body>

        <h1>Login</h1>

        <c:if test="${not empty message}">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">

                                <div class="alert alert-danger">${message}</div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${not empty logout}">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">

                                <div class="alert alert-success">${logout}</div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </c:if>
        <form action="login" method="post" id="loginform">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" /><br/>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" /><br/>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
            <%-- <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" /> --%>
        </form>

        <a href="${contextRoot}/registration">Register</a>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                const $loginForm = $("#loginform");

                if($loginForm.length){

                    $loginForm.validate({

                        rules: {

                            email: {
                                required: true
                            },

                            password: {
                                required: true
                            }
                        },

                        messages: {

                            email: {
                                required: "Please enter email"
                            },

                            password: {
                                required: "Please enter password"
                            }
                        },
                        errorElement: 'em',
                        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                            error.addClass('help-block');
                            error.insertAfter(element);
                        }

                    })

                }
            })
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**WebSecurityConfiguration.java**

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

        @Autowired
        private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.
            authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/confirm-account").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")//.failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
        }
        ...
    }
```

Error message displaying in JSP is "Invalid username and password". So how to display error message like "User not found" if `UserNotFoundException` is thrown!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't show that message as that is a security risk. Just show a general message.

Comment: In that case, right now I’m showing Invalid username and password, is that fine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` throws a BadCredentialsException if a username is not found or the password is incorrect. 
Setting this property to false will cause `UsernameNotFoundExceptions` to be thrown instead for the former.

Note this is considered less secure than throwing `BadCredentialsException` for both exceptions. To do this you have to instantiate your authentication provider, just like below:

```
  @Bean
public AuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider impl = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    impl.setUserDetailsService(yourUserDetailsService());
    impl.setHideUserNotFoundExceptions(false) ;
    return impl ;
}
```

**Warning: it's not good security practice to do so.**

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439628/spring-security-custom-exception-message-from-userdetailsservice), [setHideUserNotFoundExceptions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.15.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.html#hideUserNotFoundExceptions) and [spring security bad credentials distinguish between invalid username or password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44881171/spring-security-bad-credentials-distinguish-between-invalid-username-or-password)